# Is it safe to dereference a just-created shared_ptr in function call?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, dereference

Let A be a class.

Consider the following snippet:

```
A& a = *make_shared<A>();
CallSomeFunctionAcceptingAReferenceToA(a);
```

Now, this clearly doesn't work, because the reference counter in the shared_ptr to the instance of A is decremented to zero in the first line, and the instance is destructed. If I compile this in VS2010 I get runtime errors. That's fine. Instead, I could do this:

```
auto a = make_shared<A>();
CallSomeFunctionAcceptingAReferenceToA(*a);
```

which is safe and legal.

I want to write this more compactly, so what about this:

```
CallSomeFunctionAcceptingAReferenceToA(*make_shared<A>());
```

(note in my application the make_shared is replaced by a call to a factory which returns shared_ptr to an instance). If I compile this in VS2010, the program runs fine, but is it legal according to the C++ standard?

Comment: That's just the ordinary *lifetime of a temporary* issue. Lots of duplicates on SO.

Comment: `make_shared<A>()` creates a new `A` on the heap (in addition to the management block), and returns a `shared_ptr<A>` temporary that owns that new `A`. The temporary `shared_ptr` lasts until the end of the full-expression. The destruction of the temporary will decrease the ref-count and potentially destroy the object; if you don't delete the pointed-to `A` otherwise, the `shared_ptr` guarantees that it will live at least until the end of the full-expression.